# Is there any way to enable MacOS Lion native full screen support of Adobe Air Apps?

Tags: macos, air, adobe, osx-lion

There's only standard and none options for , but both don't support the new full screen feature from lion.

Comment: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3166056 In Automator create an Application -> add "Run AppleScript" on run {input, parameters} set a to (path to me) set p to POSIX path of a do shell script p & "../Foo.app/Contents/MacOS/Foo" return input end run Save the application in the same folder as Foo.app or adapt the path in the so shelll script command. http://adobe.hosted.jivesoftware.com/thread/931971?tstart=1